# How to check unique entity in the controller

Tags: doctrine-query, symfony-2.7

Before persisting my entity I would like to check if it doesn't already exist according to three fields.
I know how to use the annotation "UniqueEntity" but it doesn't work for me because I can't use a conventional "formType".
To summarise, my question is: In symfony 2 what's the best way to perform a unique entity check in the controller?

I already thought about get an array of Id then use an "in_array" function to decide to persist my entity or not. But I'm not sure about the efficiency of that method.

I expect that entities that already exists in my database (according to 3 fields) are not persisted.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good approach but if you can't use `UniqueEntity`, you can execute a `findBy` on your repository and decide to persist your entity or not.

```
$entityExists = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findBy(array('field1' => $value1,'field2' => $value2,'field3' => $value3));
```